# Mousewheel smooth scroll scrollbar issue

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, smooth-scrolling

I have been messing around with a pure javascript solution to smooth scroll when you use the mousewheel, and I stumbled across this code which I tweaked to my needs. Everything works fine except the scrollbar. If you press and hold the scrollbar and move it down for example, when you release it and use the mousewheel again down let's say, it reverts back to the previous position of the mousewheel and in the opposite direction. My code:

```
init()

  function init(){
        new SmoothScroll(document,120,12)
    }

    //Smooth Scroll
    function SmoothScroll(target, speed, smooth) {
        if (target === document)
            target = (document.scrollingElement 
                  || document.documentElement 
                  || document.body.parentNode 
                  || document.body) // cross browser support for document scrolling
                     
        var moving = false
        var pos = target.scrollTop
        var frame = target === document.body 
                  && document.documentElement 
                  ? document.documentElement 
                  : target // safari is the new IE

        target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrolled, { passive: false })
        target.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrolled, { passive: false }) 

        function scrolled(e) {

            e.preventDefault(); // disable default scrolling
            var delta = normalizeWheelDelta(e)
            pos += -delta * speed
            pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos, target.scrollHeight - frame.clientHeight)) // limit scrolling
            if (!moving) update()
        }

        function normalizeWheelDelta(e){
          
            if(e.detail){
                if(e.wheelDelta)
                    return e.wheelDelta/e.detail/40 * (e.detail>0 ? 1 : -1) // Opera
                else
                    return -e.detail/3 // Firefox
            }else
                return (e.wheelDelta/120)  // IE,Safari,Chrome
        }
        function update() {
            moving = true
            var delta = (pos - target.scrollTop) / smooth
            target.scrollTop += delta
            if (Math.abs(delta) >= 1) requestFrame(update)
            else moving = false
        }
        var requestFrame = function() { // requestAnimationFrame cross browser
            return (
                window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function(func) {
                    window.setTimeout(func, 1000 / 60);
                }
            );
        }() 
    }
```

I made a fiddle to exemplify the issue
https://jsfiddle.net/kgc85trn/

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

event mousescroll is  no longer supported. or check the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event

Comment: I know, but if I use the "wheel" event it doesn't work in Firefox